# ng-repeat not working on my data

Tags: angularjs

The below code works fine.

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="well well-sm">{{roomdata.status}}</div>
</div>
```

But when I use ng-repeat nothing is being displayed

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="well well-sm" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">{{x.room_type}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is my data

```
{
    status: 200,
    message: "Packages Found",
    data: [
        {
            room_type_id: "81",
            hotel_id: "72",
            room_type: "Deluxe",
            total_rooms: "5",
        }
    ]
}
```

Edit: Sorry everyone. It was my bad. I placed the wrong url in $http. It works fine now. Thank you everyone

Comment: There is no issue with your code. it works fine

Comment: is there any errors in the console.

Comment: try `ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data track by $index"`

Comment: Happened to me when I forgot to include the controller js file

Comment: If this issue was due to some kind of typo or clerical error, then I dont think this question is worth staying in SO as this ain't going to be helpful to others in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be there are no issues in your code. But in case if you have duplicate object on data array then use the `track by $index` in ng-repeat

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  $scope.roomdata = {  
   status:200,
   message:"Packages Found",
   data:[  
      {  
         room_type_id:"81",
         hotel_id:"72",
         room_type:"Deluxe",
         total_rooms:"5"
      }
   ]
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
 <div class="row">
     <div class="well well-sm" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data track by $index">{{x.room_type}}</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

can you try to remove the classes (well well-sm
) and then try to print, sometimes classes provided by UI UX people creates the problem

Comment: can you try using Chrome and click F12 and check the console logs

Answer (score 1):

please try this code..

```js
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .controller("MyController", function($scope) {
    $scope.roomdata = {
    status: 200,
    message: "Packages Found",
    data: [
        {
            room_type_id: "81",
            hotel_id: "72",
            room_type: "Deluxe",
            total_rooms: "5",
        }
        ,
         {
            room_type_id: "81",
            hotel_id: "72",
            room_type: "Deluxe100",
            total_rooms: "5",
        }
    ]
}
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
   <div class="row">
     <div class="well well-sm" ng-repeat="x in roomdata.data">{{x.room_type}}</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok, that means you are calling through ajax right?

Comment: and then just call  `$scope.roomdata = data;` in the success function

Comment: what results you are expecting?. when you call {{roomdata.status}}